SQL Server and CONCAT query
I have a view which is created from a table and this view has two columns.
What I want to do is concatenate the two columns.
The view looks like this:
Column1         Column2
------------------------------------------
I like apples   but I do not like oranges
I like bananas

What I want to do is:

If both Column 1 and Column 2 are not empty (null) as with the first record, I want to concatenate Column 1, a comma character, a space character, Column 2, a full stop character and then another space character.

If however Column 2 is empty (or null) then I simply want to concatenate Column 1 and a full stop character.


So the result should be:
I like apples, but I do not like oranges.
I like bananas.

I don't have access to the right computer and can't really remember, but what I am getting is
I like apples, but I do not like oranges.
I like bananas. .

I get an unwanted space and full stop if column 2 is null

While asking a question, you need to provide a minimal reproducible example:
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements.
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL.
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in the #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;).

Built-in CONCAT_WS() function is exactly for your scenario. It is available starting from SQL Server 2017 onwards.

CONCAT_WS(', ', column1, column2) + '.' works fine

Give this a try:
with YourViewName (Column1,Column2) as (
  select 'I like apples',   'but I do not like oranges' union all
  select 'I like bananas', null
)
  SELECT 
  CASE 
    WHEN Column2 IS NULL OR Column2 = '' THEN Column1 + '.'
    ELSE Column1 + ', ' + Column2 + '.'
  END AS ConcatenatedColumn
FROM YourViewName;



Try this. Fiddle query.
Select * into #FruiteLikings From 
(Select 'I like apples' Col1, 'but I do not like oranges' Col2 Union
Select 'I like bananas', ''
) A 

Select Col1, Col2 
  ,CONCAT(col1, Case Col2 When '' Then '' Else CONCAT(', ', Col2) End, '.') Col3
  from #FruiteLikings

Drop Table #FruiteLikings


